# Read a multidimensional post request using Django / Python

Tags: python, django, post, multidimensional-array

I'm sending a post request like this:

```
photo[1][id] = 1234
photo[1][size] = 4x4
photo[1][quantity] = 2
photo[2][id] = 4567
photo[2][size] = 4x6
photo[2][quantity] = 1
...
```

What is the best way to read this data using Django/Python?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [querystring-parser](https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser).

For example, if you had the following form being submitted via POST to your view:

```
<input name="photo['1']['id']"       value="1234">
<input name="photo['1']['size']"     value="4x4">
<input name="photo['1']['quantity']" value="2">
<input name="photo['2']['id']"       value="4567">
<input name="photo['2']['size']"     value="4x6">
<input name="photo['2']['quantity']" value="1">
```

In your view you can parse it like this:

```
from querystring_parser import parser
post_dict = parser.parse(request.POST.urlencode())
print post_dict
# {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': u'<crazy hash goes here>', 
#  u'photo': 
#    {1: {u'id': u'1234', u'size': u'4x4', u'quantity': u'2'},
#     2: {u'id': u'4567', u'size': u'4x6', u'quantity': u'1'}
#  }
```

Accessing the first photo's size is as simple as `post_dic[1]['size']`