# Django POST request does not organize data as expected

Tags: python, django

So I have a form that I'm posting to a Django app.  The field names are such as:
field[section][name][attr] where section, name, etc. can have any number of values.  When I attempt to access the data in the POST request these are the exact keys in the QueryDict, so to access the data I have to do something like request.POST.get('field[section][name][attr]').  Why doesn't Django create the hierarchy so I can do something like

```
fields = request.POST.getlist('field')
```

and then go deeper from there with something like

```
for section, value in fields:
    for field_name, attributes in value:
```

It seems I have to use regex's to process the form data.  Am I missing something?

ADDITIONAL INFO: My field form elements are defined as:

```
input type="hidden" name="field[{{ section|underscore|lower }}][{{field.name }}][label]" value="{{ field.label }}"
input type="hidden" name="field[{{ section|underscore|lower }}][{{field.name }}][help]" value="{{ field.help }}"
input type="hidden" name="field[{{ section|underscore|lower }}][{{field.name }}][kind]" value="{{ field.kind }}"
```

So POST data comes in as:

```
'field[section_name][field_name][label]': label_value
'field[section_name][field_name][help]': help_value
'field[section_name][field_name][kind]': kind_value
```

For example using request.POST.lists():

```
('section[]', ['Qualys', 'Notifications'])
('field[qualys][test][label]', ['Test'])
('field[qualys][test][help]', ['My help text.'])
('field[qualys][test][kind]', ['string'])
```

So if I want to retrieve the label value, for example, I have to:

```
request.POST.get('field[section_name][field_name][label]')
```

Since section_name and field_name are not known in advance I have to use a regex to pull them out.

Comment: Additionally if I define a form element to have multiple values using a name such as name="values[]", in order to access all of the values I have to use
    request.POST.getlist('values[]')
rather than what I would expect:
    request.POST.getlist('values')

Comment: Tracey, so what do the keys look like out of the POST (can you provide an example)?  Also, are you using a regular form or modelform?

Comment: I'm using a manually, dynamically created form.  Users can add sections which adds name="section[]" entries, and then add fields to the sections.  So can have multiple hidden form elements whose name is "section[]".  The POST data comes in like: ('section[]', ['Qualys', 'Notifications']).  I would expect, as in other environments such as Rails, the key to be 'section' and the value to be a list of the sections.

Comment: Django doesn't support parsing multi-dimensional arrays like this - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500137/read-a-multidimensional-post-request-using-django-python for some suggestions.